# Undefined Method map for housework: String acts_as_taggable_on

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im using acts_as_taggabe gem for my rails todo app project. In my 
index.html file, Im performing an array method map on task.tag_list, 
task.tag_list is supposed to return me an array of tags which ill operate 
on but im getting error. It works alright without the map method. It shows 
all the tags as desired.

```
    #index.html.erb
    <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
        <tr>
          <td width="60%"><%= task.task %></td>
          <td width="20%"><%= task.deadline %></td>
          <td width="20%"><%= task.tag_list.map {|x| x + "testing"} %>
          <td><%= link_to 'Show', task_path(task), class: 'button'%></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_task_path(task), class: 'button' %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Delete ', task_path(task),
                      method: :delete,
                      data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'button' %> 
   </td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>

    #routes.rb
      get '/tags/:tag', to: 'tasks#index', as: :tag

    #tasks_controller
      def index
        if params[:tag]
          @tasks = current_user.tasks.tagged_with(params[:tag])
        else
        @tasks = current_user.tasks
        end
      end
```

Comment: can you show app/models/task.rb

Comment: omg i got it alr.. i didnt add act_as_taggable to my model.. thanks a lot

Comment: @RundingWang How were you getting it working without map method as you weren't had act_as_taggable in your model?